# Exclude CSS property from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a navigation bar at the top of my site, a simple HTML un-ordered list:

```
<div class="navitemcontainer">
            <ul class="navlistul">
                <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Behind this I have some basic CSS formatting:

```
.navitemcontainer
{
padding-top: 40px;
padding-right: 10px;
}

.navlistul
{
list-style-type: none;
}

.navitemcontainer li
{
float: right;
opacity: 0.5;

}

.navitemcontainer li~li
{
border-right: 3px ridge #FFF;
}

.navitemcontainer li a
{
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
font-size: 20px;

font-family: 'Allerta Stencil';
}

.navitemcontainer li:active
{
margin-top: 2px;
}
```

I also have a Javascript function to change the opacity of the links on mouseenter/mouseleave:

```
function opaquelinkchange()
{
$(".logo, .navlistul li").on
(
    {
        mouseenter : function()
        {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
        },
        mouseleave : function()
        {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo(250, 0.5);
        }
    }
)
}
```

The issue I have is when the mouse enters the navigation links, it also lights up (sets the opacity) of the CSS property below:

```
.navitemcontainer li~li
{
border-right: 3px ridge #FFF;
}
```

I understand that this is correct and there is no fault here, but I would like to have the border-right property remain opaque and not light up upon mouseenter.

Is there any way of excluding this CSS property from the JavaScript code?

I am fairly new to HTML, CSS and JS so please excuse me if this is a stupid question and for the code formatting.

Thanks for any help.

J

Comment: You can't change an element's opacity and have it's border-opacity be different.

Comment: I know there is something like a :not for JS, can this be adapted to pick certain CSS properties or is this strictly for class selection?

Comment: The JS :not can't target a border either. It's like trying to target a background-color, or a font-size. It's a CSS property.

Comment: :not would be used strictly on a selector and not a CSS property. Can you set the opacity of your href instead? If not, perhaps a span as the child of li and parent of href.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Thanks for your help. I'll find another way to do this, probably by either creating a seperate element, or getting the current format to look half decent. Cheers

Comment: As @chrismauck said. Use opacity in your `<a>` element and keep borders on `<li>`. Set `display:block` and `padding` to adjust it.

Comment: @JHiggins could you just add and remove a class to the `li` to change it's look in your jQuery? Or maybe use `.animate()` instead.

Comment: Its like saying you want a div to have opacity 0 but element inside it to have opacity 1....it just won't work.     Listen to @chrismauck